# pull to refresh returns data twice

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-activity, pull-to-refresh

I,m getting data from JSON feed.

I'm able to do pull-to-refresh and it's working fine, but it's not bringing new data only, it brings all data over and over again, so every time I refresh it brings all results like same results and repeat them inside the app.

**im using Volly library.**

my Data JSON Looks Like

http://twaa9l.com/ji/feed.json

here is My Code :

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Cache.Entry;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.twaa9l.photosee.feed.FeedItem;
import com.twaa9l.photosee.feed.FeedListAdapter;
import com.twaa9l.photosee.library.AppController;
import com.twaa9l.photosee.library.SessionManagement;
import com.twaa9l.photosee.library.UploadPhoto;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    protected SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://twaa9l.com/ji/feed.json";
    // Session Manager Class
    SessionManagement session;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //refresh();
        // Session class instance
        session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());

        /**
         * Call this function whenever you want to check user login
         * This will redirect user to LoginActivity is he is not
         * logged in
         * */
        session.checkLogin();

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();


        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(mOnRefreshListener);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(
                R.color.swipeRefresh1,
                R.color.swipeRefresh2,
                R.color.swipeRefresh3,
                R.color.swipeRefresh4);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // These two lines not needed,
        // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
        getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

            getNewPosts();

    }


    private void getNewPosts() {

            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                                if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
                                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                int lastStoredTimeStamp = 0;
                if(i == feedArray.length()){
                     lastStoredTimeStamp = feedObj.getInt("timeStamp");
                }

                if(feedObj.getInt("timeStamp") > lastStoredTimeStamp){
                    feedItems.add(item);
                    }
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();

        switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            session.logoutUser();
            break;
        case R.id.addPhoto:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, UploadPhoto.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    protected OnRefreshListener mOnRefreshListener = new OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "We Are Refreshing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getNewPosts();  
        }
    };


}
```

What i want to do is, only bringing the new results and append them to the existing results in the app,

NOT repeating the results.

**Note :** This Question is not DUPLICATED because i looked for all question the has pull to refresh problems in here and nothing worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the server from which you are pulling the data needs to return data based on the timestamp you passed.

For example when you query you specify the timestamp "T" of the data which you have and the server returns data only after timestamp "T"

If the server doesnot support this mechanism then on the client side you need to make sure you are adding data items to the listview list which have the timestamp > "T".

Something like following:

```
          long lastStoredTimeStamp = 0;//This should be in constructor
/**
 * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
 * */
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

            // Image might be null sometimes
            String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("image");
            item.setImge(image);
            item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
            item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
            item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

            // url might be null sometimes
            String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("url");
            item.setUrl(feedUrl);

            if(i == feedArray.length()-1){
                 lastStoredTimeStamp = feedObj.getLong("timeStamp");
            }

            if(feedObj.getLong("timeStamp") > lastStoredTimeStamp){
                feedItems.add(item);
                }
        }

        // notify data changes to list adapater
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: so i should store timestamp for each feed item ? or what, excuse me but im still beginner in android and json data

Comment: yup you need to store timestamp for each item or atleast for last item.

Comment: also, i have a cache of the data maybe that's something i can use to compare IF the data exists don't add it and if not add it to the top of the list, the problem is i don't know how to compare them

Comment: could you help me do that, please just headlines and i will follow along with it,

Comment: @youssefsubehi  if(Long.longValue(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"))>lastStoredTimeStamp){
                 feedItems.add(item);}

Comment: @youssefsubehi I edited the code..let me knw if it works

Comment: No it didn't work, it still the same, get the data twice after refresh

Comment: @youssefsubehi check now..Also please debug the code line by line so that we can eliminate coding errors

Comment: It Worked by not conflicting the results Thank You Soo Much, BUT i don't get the new results Now :(

Comment: Welcome..I think it might be network or server issue.Please dont forget to accept the answer

Comment: i will, but when i navigate to another activity and get back to the main activity it show me the new results and when i pull to refresh it doesn't show me the new results, what u think the problem might be :(

Comment: you probably need to debug the code line by line..it is not very clear from here the probable reason for it